# SQL DQS Domain properties 'Use leading values'

Tags: sql-server, data-quality-services

In the SQL DQS Client knowledge base (domain management), there is a checkbox for 'Use leading values'. I am looking for use case example of this please.

"Select this checkbox to specify that the leading value in a group of synonyms will be output instead of a value that is a synonym to it. Deselect Use Leading Values to specify that each synonym value is output in its correct or corrected form, and is not replaced by the leading value for its group."

A similar option is also available when configuring 'Domain values' section that allows which of the synonym I would like to set as leading. So I was wondering what is the purpose of that checkbox in the 'Domain properties' as shown in below screenshot.

[image: Use leading values]

Answer (score 1):

This checkbox make sure that data is automatically corrected to it's leading value in KB, if there exist synonyms pair in KB.
If not checked, DQS will show the subjected value as correct but wouldn't correct it to leading value.

For example, "United States Of America" and "USA" are synonyms values in your KB, where first value is the leading value. DQS will automatically change "USA" to it's leading value if that box is checked else, it would just indicate "USA" as correct value.

[For more details visit this link.](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/jeremykashel/post/Data-Quality-Services-Leading-Values)